# Unable to connect to AWS RDS instance from docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-rds

On my Windows 10 host machine I am able to connect to a private SQL Server RDS instance running in AWS. However, a Docker container running locally on the same machine is unable to connect with the same connection string.

From the Docker container I am able to telnet to the server on 1433 successfully. However, when I connect from code, it seems to be unable to create a connection. No exception is thrown, but this code hangs:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
   // Do something
}
```

I am able to successfully connect to SQL Server when it is running on a EC2 instance. It appears to be specific to RDS.

Fails with both the name and IP address.

Comment: I don't remember doing anything special to use the RDS. What is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in SQLClient as described on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222). There were two fixes that worked:

1. Downgrade the project from Net Core 3.1 to 2.2
2. Update Docker file to use `aspnet:3.1-bionic` instead of `aspnet:3.1-buster-slim` and `sdk:3.1-bionic` instead of `sdk:3.1-buster`